# Remove sessionStorage property on tab close for all tabs

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ecmascript-6, webforms

I am very new to .NET development and working on an application written in ASP with web forms. The application has a page with a table, and when a table row is clicked it opens a new tab. The new tab has a form with pre-filled data from the row that was clicked. I accomplished this using sessionStorage.

Now I want to write some JS that removes the item from sessionStorage for both tabs when just the form tab is closed. I have tried the following but when I close the form tab, and check sessionStorage in the table tab, the property is still there. Any thoughts? Thanks and anything helps!

The following code is run in the content footer of the .aspx file where I have all my other, working JS:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="contentfooter" runat="server">
    <script>
        window.addEventListener('unload', (e) => {
          sessionStorage.removeItem('rowDataJSON');
        });
    </script>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: JavaScript needs to be enclosed by `<script></script>` tags.

Comment: Thanks @EduardoAlmeida. It is. I just forgot to add the tags to this code snippet in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use sessionStorage for this. Because from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage)

> Opening a page in a new tab or window creates a new session with the value of the top-level browsing context, which differs from how session cookies work.

What you could use is [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

Comment: Thanks @abishek for your suggestion. My question then is why does it work when I save a property in sessionStorage in the table window and then retrieve that data from sessionStorage in the form window? If these are two separate sessions then how can I access the data from one tab in the other, because I already have and it works.

Comment: In your first case, you must be setting the sessionStorage first and then the new tab. The new tab has the top-level browsing context, which in this case comes from the previous tab. But any modification you do after the tabs are opened they are not in sync. In simpler words, the new tab will have the sessionStorage of the previous tab when it was opened but any changes from now on in any of the tabs will not reflect in others

Comment: Switching to localStorage worked perfectly. Thanks Abishek.